# When I use ping command for my discord bot I get error

Tags: discord.js

When I use the ping command, I get the following error:
`repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1`

The **error-log** is below:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).spilt(/ +/);
                                                    ^

TypeError: message.content.slice(...).spilt is not a function
```

My whole code is below:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const keepAlive = require('./server');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
 

client.on('message', message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).spilt(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  if(command === 'ping'){
    message.channel.send('pong!');
  }
}) 



keepAlive();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Does anybody know, how to fix it?

Comment: @Flo Why would a regex like `/ +/` be invalid? It matches whitespaces. If you check your link you can see that _"the separator can be a simple string or it can be a regular expression."_

Comment: Anyway, it's a typo; `spilt` should be `split`.

Answer (score 0):

you misspelled `split` and typed `spilt`

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/); //change this line
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  if(command === 'ping'){
    message.channel.send('pong!');
  }
})
```